# JMeter : Constant Throughput Timer not working as expected

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-4.0

I have a single Thread Group defined with 200 threads. I have a HTTP Request defined within the thread group and a Constant throughput timer defined within the HTTP Request. The Target throughput (samples/min) defined is 5400 samples/min (Since I want to achieve a throughput of 90 requests/second).

I am running the test in non-GUI mode. This is the summary report I see though:

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using Elasticsearch_Backup.jmx
Starting the test @ Thu Jun 14 02:38:44 UTC 2018 (1528943924375)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary +    187 in 00:00:46 =    4.1/s Avg: 34306 Min:     4 Max: 45427 Err:    13 (6.95%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary +    532 in 00:00:29 =   18.2/s Avg: 14309 Min:     3 Max: 53467 Err:     6 (1.13%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary =    719 in 00:01:15 =    9.6/s Avg: 19510 Min:     3 Max: 53467 Err:    19 (2.64%)
summary +   1318 in 00:00:30 =   43.8/s Avg:  4949 Min:     2 Max: 13973 Err:    10 (0.76%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary =   2037 in 00:01:45 =   19.4/s Avg: 10089 Min:     2 Max: 53467 Err:    29 (1.42%)
summary +    410 in 00:00:31 =   13.4/s Avg: 11060 Min:     4 Max: 27259 Err:     5 (1.22%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary =   2447 in 00:02:16 =   18.0/s Avg: 10251 Min:     2 Max: 53467 Err:    34 (1.39%)
summary +    300 in 00:01:00 =    5.0/s Avg: 23086 Min:     3 Max: 76712 Err:     4 (1.33%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary =   2747 in 00:03:16 =   14.0/s Avg: 11653 Min:     2 Max: 76712 Err:    38 (1.38%)
summary +     95 in 00:00:31 =    3.0/s Avg: 57490 Min:     3 Max: 93311 Err:     1 (1.05%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary =   2842 in 00:03:47 =   12.5/s Avg: 13185 Min:     2 Max: 93311 Err:    39 (1.37%)
summary +     84 in 00:00:28 =    3.0/s Avg: 76465 Min: 57500 Max: 119520 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary =   2926 in 00:04:15 =   11.5/s Avg: 15002 Min:     2 Max: 119520 Err:    39 (1.33%)
summary +     98 in 00:00:30 =    3.3/s Avg: 62451 Min: 18075 Max: 121665 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary =   3024 in 00:04:45 =   10.6/s Avg: 16539 Min:     2 Max: 121665 Err:    39 (1.29%)
summary +    204 in 00:00:30 =    6.8/s Avg: 47297 Min:  8554 Max: 152392 Err:     2 (0.98%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary =   3228 in 00:05:15 =   10.2/s Avg: 18483 Min:     2 Max: 152392 Err:    41 (1.27%)
summary +    723 in 00:00:30 =   24.1/s Avg: 10706 Min:     4 Max: 161663 Err:     2 (0.28%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary =   3951 in 00:05:45 =   11.4/s Avg: 17060 Min:     2 Max: 161663 Err:    43 (1.09%)
summary +   1089 in 00:00:30 =   36.2/s Avg:  5725 Min:     3 Max: 159356 Err:     3 (0.28%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary =   5040 in 00:06:15 =   13.4/s Avg: 14611 Min:     2 Max: 161663 Err:    46 (0.91%)
```

I dont see the requests/second go more than 43. Is something wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

[Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) can only **pause** threads in order to **limit** JMeter's throughput to the defined value. As per documentation>

> Of course the throughput will be lower **if the server is not capable of handling it**, or if other timers or time-consuming test elements prevent it.

Looking into the Average Response Time which can be as high as > 1 minute my expectation is that your server simply cannot respond fast enough so you are not reaching the desired throughput due to some form of [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing).

If high response times are expected - you can try increasing number of threads in the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or even better switch to [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Concurrency-Thread-Group) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) combination. These 2 test elements can be coupled via [feedback function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function) so JMeter will automatically kick off more threads if current amount is not enough to reach/maintain the desired throughput. You can install both elements using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)